# RSpec working on Mac but not Windows

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm trying to run a very simple RSpec script on Windows, however whenever I use the command `rspec <filename>.rb` the command prompt just prints an empty line and the prompts me to enter the next command.

However, when I run the same command on my Mac, with the same simple rb file, it gives an output (albeit an error), telling me what is wrong.

How can I troubleshoot this and get this working on Windows? I've tried uninstalling ruby and all it's gems and reinstalling with only the gems I need, but it still produces nothing in command prompt when I run it and I'm not sure where to go next to got about fixing the issue of not displaying an output.

Comment: Start with simplest file which has 1 example that works. Can you get that to work?

Comment: The problem seemed to be that it only worked on Windows when I added _spec to the end of the filename, and that the file I had did not have that extension. The example itself was fairly simple - just loads a single webpage then ends. I just have never used RSpec before and did not know where to turn when I encountered this error, but found a solution in the end. Thank you for your suggestion, I am happy now this is working.